# C++ How to read a file with values separated with commas

Tags: c++

I have a file with 198 (however it could at any point be between 0-200) lines. Each line of my file looks like this:

```
Urdnot Wrex,2.75,198846.13
Urdnot Bakara,3,189484.84
Hannah Shepard,1.75,188145.14
David Anderson,2.25,182169.46
Kasumi Goto,2.75,176795.83
```

This is my code, however, it does not want to work.

```
int index = 0; // The index of the file.

while(index <= 200) {
    in.ignore(256, ',');
    in >> employeeName;
    in.ignore(256, ',');
    in >> employeeScore;
    in.ignore(256, '\n');
    in >> employeeSalary;

    cout << index << ": " << employeeName << ", " << employeeScore << ", " << employeeSalary << endl;
    index++;
}
```

However, with a file with 198 lines it only reads 3 with the output being:

```
0: 2.75,198846.13, 3, 0
1: 2.75,198846.13, 3, 0
2: 2.75,198846.13, 3
```

If anyone has any ideas on how to make it work, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
#include <fstream>

std::ifstream infile("thefile.txt");
if (infile.is_open()) {
    float number;
    std::string str;
    char c;
    while (infile >> str >> c >> number && c == ',')
        cout << number << " " << str << "\n";
}
infile.close();
```

Comment: What if you have a case like a (name, 1)? ( it won't work since the name, is considered as a whole world, and not name + delimiter ',' ). A nice solution is to use std::getline with stringstream for those kinds of parsing stuff.